# Reading xbrl with python

Tags: python, xbrl

I am trying find particular tag in an xbrl file. I originally tried using python-xbrl package, but it is not exactly what I want, so I based my code on the one available from the package.

Here's the part of xbrl that I am interested in

```
<us-gaap:LiabilitiesCurrent contextRef="eol_PE2035----1510-Q0008_STD_0_20150627_0" unitRef="iso4217_USD" decimals="-6" id="id_5025426_6FEF05CB-B19C-4D84-AAF1-79B431731049_1_24">65285000000</us-gaap:LiabilitiesCurrent>
<us-gaap:Liabilities contextRef="eol_PE2035----1510-Q0008_STD_0_20150627_0" unitRef="iso4217_USD" decimals="-6" id="id_5025426_6FEF05CB-B19C-4D84-AAF1-79B431731049_1_28">147474000000</us-gaap:Liabilities>
```

Here is the code

`python-xbrl` package is based on `beautifulsoup4` and several other packages.

```
liabilities = xbrl.find_all(name=re.compile("(us-gaap:Liabilities)",
                          re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE))
```

I get the value for `us-gaap:LiabilitiesCurrent`, but I want value for `us-gaap:Liabilities`. 
Right now as soon as it finds a match it, stores it. But in many cases its the wrong match due to the tag format in xbrl. I believe I need to change `re.compile()` part to make it work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with a `$` dollar sign at the end to indicate not to match anything else following the dollar sign:

```
liabilities = xbrl.find_all(name=re.compile("(us-gaap:Liabilities$)",
                          re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE))
```

Comment: That worked thank you! For some reason I thought that `$` should be at the beginning of the string, and obviously that wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be very wary about using this approach to parsing XBRL (or indeed, any XML with namespaces in it).  "us-gaap:Liabilities" is a QName, consisting of a prefix ("us-gaap") and a local name ("Liabilities").  The prefix is just a shorthand for a full namespace URI such as "http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2015-01-31", which is defined by a namespace declaration, usually at the top of the document.  If you look at the top of the document you'll see something like:

xmlns:us-gaap="http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2015-01-31"

This means that within the scope of this document, "us-gaap" is taken to mean that full namespace URI.

XML creators are free to use whatever prefixes they want, so there is no guarantee that the element will actually be called "us-gaap:Liabilities" across all documents that you encounter.

beautifulsoup4 has very limited support for namespaces, so I wouldn't recommend it as a starting point for building an XBRL processor.  It may be worth taking a look at the Arelle project, which is a full XBRL processor, and will make it easier to do other tasks such as finding the labels and other information associated with facts in the taxonomy.

Comment: Indeed in XML prefixes are irrelevant. In XBRL (which is an abstraction layer above XML that has its own data model), the treatment of prefixes is a bit different and it is guaranteed that us-gaap will be the prefix in all filings, because this is enforced by the Securities and Exchange Commission's rules. In fact, us-gaap is versioned and the namespace changes every year.

Comment: See for example: https://xbrl.us/xbrl-taxonomy/2024-us-gaap/ ("Recommended Namespace Prefix")

I completely support your statement on the importance of using an XBRL processor rather than parsing the data manually.

Answer (score 1):

We just released a new XBRL Python library (free, open source) today called [Brel](https://pypi.org/project/brel-xbrl/) that provides a higher-level abstraction on XBRL following the standardized model. It is still in an early alpha stage, but we are focused on fixing the bugs reported to us.

Your use case would look like this (in this example by downlading [this report](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019323000106/0000320193-23-000106-index.htm)):

```
from brel import Filing, pprint
filing = Filing.open("report/aapl-20230701_htm.xml")
liabilities = filing.get_concept("us-gaap:Liabilities")
facts = filing.get_facts_by_concept(liabilities)
```

You can pretty-print the facts like so:

```
pprint(facts)
```

Leading to this output:

[image]

But Brel also allows you to access the values, context, etc with more Python code.

```
filtered = [fact for fact in facts if fact.get_period().get_instant_period().year == 2023]
print(filtered[0].get_value_as_int())
```

Output:

```
274764000000
```

Comment: This sounds like an exciting project that the world badly needs. Arelle needs some competition.

Comment: It's very kind of you! I have a lot of respect for the Arelle team and we have the same goal of making the XBRL ecosystem accessible to all.