# Parsing XBRL using python

Tags: python, xbrl

I am working on parsing values from xbrl. I base my code on python-xbrl package, but changed it a bit to suit my needs. The package uses `beautifulsoup4`

I am using code below to find one value that I am interested in. I am using `if` statement because different companies use different tag names for the same thing.

For example AAPL uses `us-gaap:CostOfGoodsAndServicesSold`, and ADBE uses `us-gaap:CostOfRevenue`.

## This code works as intended, giving me the correct value 29924000000

```
    #COST_GOOD_SOLD
    COST_GOOD_SOLD = xbrl.find_all(name=re.compile("(us-gaap:CostOfGoodsAndServicesSold$)",
                                                   re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE))
    gaap_obj.COST_GOOD_SOLD = self.data_processing(COST_GOOD_SOLD, xbrl, ignore_errors,
                                                   logger, context_ids)
    if gaap_obj.COST_GOOD_SOLD ==0 or gaap_obj.COST_GOOD_SOLD==None:
        COST_GOOD_SOLD = xbrl.find_all(name=re.compile("(us-gaap:CostOfRevenue$)",
                                                           re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE))
        gaap_obj.COST_GOOD_SOLD = self.data_processing(COST_GOOD_SOLD, xbrl, ignore_errors,
                                                       logger, context_ids)
```

## XBRL

```
<us-gaap:CostOfGoodsAndServicesSold contextRef="eol_PE2035----1510-Q0008_STD_91_20150627_0" unitRef="iso4217_USD" decimals="-6" id="id_5025426_2D2AD7F5-3575-48A0-9F08-7F1EBE173C23_1_1">29924000000</us-gaap:CostOfGoodsAndServicesSold>
```

## This code returns zero, while I want -1808000000

```
    #NET_CURR_DEBT
    NET_CURR_DEBT = xbrl.find_all(name = re.compile("(us-gaap:ProceedsFromRepaymentsOfCommercialPaper$)",
                                                    re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE))
    gaap_obj.NET_CURR_DEBT = self.data_processing(NET_CURR_DEBT, xbrl, ignore_errors,
                                                  logger, context_ids)
    if NET_CURR_DEBT==0 or NET_CURR_DEBT==None:
        NET_CURR_DEBT = xbrl.find_all(name = re.compile("(us-gaap:RepaymentsOfLongTermDebtAndCapitalSecurities$)",
                                                        re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE))
        gaap_obj.NET_CURR_DEBT = self.data_processing(NET_CURR_DEBT, xbrl, ignore_errors,
                                                      logger, context_ids)
```

## XBRL

```
<us-gaap:ProceedsFromRepaymentsOfCommercialPaper contextRef="eol_PE2035----1510-Q0008_STD_273_20150627_0" unitRef="iso4217_USD" decimals="-6" id="id_5025426_049B4F11-216C-4D4B-A41F-32F1F55F967F_1_32">-1808000000</us-gaap:ProceedsFromRepaymentsOfCommercialPaper>
```

I have several other values that I am parsing, but they all have the same structure as the code I have attached. 
My output is a dataframe where first column is value names `(COST_GOOD_SOLD, NET_CURR_DEBT, ect)` and the second column is values from `XML` file.

I can't figure out why identical chunks of code don't work. It seems that I am doing the same thing in both cases. Finding a value and storing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One difference is that the if statement checks gaap_obj.COST_GOOD_SOLD in the first case, but just NET_CURR_DEBT in the second.

It's hard to comment further without seeing what self.data_processing actually does, but does your code cope with the fact that the same element may appear multiple times in an XBRL document (differentiated by different contexts)?

As I commented on your previous question ([Reading xbrl with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33903843/reading-xbrl-with-python)), I wouldn't recommend beautifulsoup for parsing XBRL as its namespace support is incomplete.  You'd be better with a proper XBRL library, that will also take care of processing the contexts etc. for you.

Comment: The code does deal with the fact that an element could appear several times. I tried using Arelle, but the link on their website to documentation [link](http://arelle.rtfd.org/) just gives a list of modules.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of omissions and misleading stub methods and parameters that do nothing in python-xbrl.  I wouldn't trust the code without reading it through.

Here is an example -- a method called parse_unique() that does run some sort of filter on the XML, but then ignores it:

```
@classmethod
def parse_unique(self, xbrl):
    """
    Parse company unique entities from XBRL and return an Unique object.
    """
    unique_obj = Unique()

    unique_data = xbrl.find_all(re.compile('^(?!us-gaap|xbrl*):\s*'))

    return unique_obj
```

and then the definition of Unique:

```
class Unique(object):
    def __init__(self):
        return None
```

I'm not addressing your issue directly with these comments, but suggest you look closely at the code to make sure it's doing what you expect.